# able to call an api via curl but same api hangs when called from nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl

So scenario is like this I

1. From Local system -  able to call api via curl and via nodejs code.
   mitmproxy screenshots of connection details are in screenshot.

[image]

2. From server hosted on linode - able to call api via curl but same code working on local gets stuck.
   mitmproxy screenshots of connection details are in screenshot.

[image]

From what i am guessing its most likely related to ssl handshake being stuck somewhere. What is bothering me since last few days is request and headers are same from curl and nodejs then why different behaviour

sample curl `curl 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=stock_fut' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1464035869.1595747215; RT="z=1&dm=nseindia.com&si=d2d25dd8-0b59-4941-a83c-9e3fd2ff9f63&ss=kdllvs49&sl=0&tt=0&bcn=%2F%2F684d0d37.akstat.io%2F&ul=36pqu&hd=36pwb"; ak_bmsc=32ED2E364503B6429496808D1A081032DFC42B6C6C2B0000013A315F40BDEA22~pl0PkvDhq66QJbIByCPofydTlTrNC70ggGqe1TUq9qks8cAr8R3eZemC9KyklftDSOsn0lHOiNNrEUdQWVD7K9oyJ4mGjON/9EjkvUCiHECyXvRkGJmEOaZcBzDtdvX+B8wg8spNZ3RI3jWLg7w+Asr66XwLm8l04X6nfSo9UkF+iOv49hjP4Lfhb4tC6p74oLmL/TQsX5a1gQlb9MGZznGPrXhhxFu1Rd1m3XD9/PToM=' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'TE: Trailers'`

sample nodejs code -NODE_DEBUG=* node mytest.js

[image]

```
var request = require('request');
var https = require('https')
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  secureProtocol: "TLSv1_2_method"
});

var headers = {
  'Host': 'www.nseindia.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
  'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1464035869.1595747215; RT=z=1&dm=nseindia.com&si=d2d25dd8-0b59-4941-a83c-9e3fd2ff9f63&ss=kdllvs49&sl=0&tt=0&bcn=%2F%2F684d0d37.akstat.io%2F&ul=36pqu&hd=36pwb; ak_bmsc=32ED2E364503B6429496808D1A081032DFC42B6C6C2B0000013A315F40BDEA22~pl0PkvDhq66QJbIByCPofydTlTrNC70ggGqe1TUq9qks8cAr8R3eZemC9KyklftDSOsn0lHOiNNrEUdQWVD7K9oyJ4mGjON/9EjkvUCiHECyXvRkGJmEOaZcBzDtdvX+B8wg8spNZ3RI3jWLg7w+Asr66XwLm8l04X6nfSo9UkF+iOv49hjP4Lfhb4tC6p74oLmL/TQsX5a1gQlb9MGZznGPrXhhxFu1Rd1m3XD9/PToM='

};

var options = {
    url: 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=stock_fut',
    headers: headers
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

(async function(){
  if(require.main==module){
    console.log('before')
    let data = await fetch(options.url, {
      headers: {
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'      
      },
      agent:httpsAgent
                                        }).then(res => res.json())
    console.log(data)
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which works,

```
curl -v --output test.gz -H User-Agent: -H Accept: -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" "https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=stock_fut"
```

the output is stored in test.gz

Edit: (Some more explaination)
I think that the server accept some specific encoding only, which I have specified using `-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"` and need to keep the connection alive. The remaining parameters are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Would you please explain this code to make the answer more helpful?